# Populating Fixed Values for Document Properties

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need to find a way to automatically populate a SpotFire document property's fixed values. I want these fixed values to be a list of all the visualizations within a dashboard, so that a user can choose a visualization using a drop down menu. The document property in question is of type string, and I plan on using the set of all visualization titles that exist within the document as the document properties possible values.

I've tried simply updating the document property value using IronPython scripting as shown below, but this value isn't added to the properties fixed values.

```
Document.Properties["MyProperty"] = "Property Value"
```

This changes the document properties value, but I can't have the user select that value from a drop down menu. I could simply populate the fixed values manually, but I want this to be easily implemented on other dashboards, so I am looking for an IronPython script or something similar to populate the fixed values automatically.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't supported (or at least it wasn't last time I tried https://community.tibco.com/questions/spotfire-add-new-values-dropdown-list-using-script).

My workaround was along the lines of one of the posts in the link above... an additional table to the file which contained the tab names populated by an IP script. My listbox referenced the unique values in it.